# .Net.Mail not throwing exceptions with exchange SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, exchange-server

I'm having a problem when using .Net.Mail library with an exchange server. The problem is I'm not getting any exceptions when for example domain or email does not exist.

my Code:

```
  public async Task SendEmailAsync(Email email)
  {
        SmtpClient _client = new SmtpClient("smtp.dummyExchange.cz");
        _client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("credential", "pass");
        _client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        _client.EnableSsl = true;
        _client.Port = 25;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("fake@fake.cz");
        mail.To.Add('fake@gmail.fake');
        mail.Subject = 'subject';
        mail.Body = Getmailbody();
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        string messageId = $"<{GenerateMessageId()}>";
        mail.Headers.Add("Message-ID", messageId);

        try
        {
            await _client.SendMailAsync(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            mail.Dispose();
        }....
```

I tried using exactly the same code with an external relay SMTP server and everything works just fine. So either its the exchange settings problem or I'm just using the SmtpClient wrong with the exchange?

**Edit:**

For example, when sending email via relay smtp server I get this exception:

```
"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 4.1.2 <fake@gmail.fake>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found"
```

But when using exchange, there is no exception.

**Edit:**

Exchange version: Exchange 2016 CU13

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the email server raises no communication errors and just sens an email to the receipment saying "address not found", then your code will not hit the `catch` block. You could check if the format of the address is wrong using a [MailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: But when using the relay server I get for example this exception... "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 4.1.2 <xxx@xxxx.fake>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found ", but when using exchange I get no exception.

Comment: Looks like the relay server waits for the actual delivery so it raises the wrong destination exception but your exchange server does not wait or is configured not to tell the sender.